# .htaccess php_value auto_prepend_file from document root

Tags: php, apache

Is it possible to set the `auto_prepend_file` from `.htaccess` to always use the root of the server as its document root?

I have `php_value auto_prepend_file middleware/middleware_pre.php` in `.htaccess` in my root.

At the moment for every sub directory I have to add an additional `.htaccess` file and call the prepend logic with an additional `../` every time. For exapmle, one folder down, `php_value auto_prepend_file ../middleware/middleware_pre.php`

How do i make it to where i only need the one `.htaccess` file in the root and just have the code use the relative path from the root to prepend?

Comment: Just use the absolute path of middleware_pre.php.

Comment: @Olivier yea im trying to avoid doing that if possible. I may end up having to, but with how the server is setup its kind of a pain.

Comment: Very(!) long shot, but I don't suppose using server variables in combination with `php_value` works? `php_value auto_prepend_file %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/middleware/middleware_pre.php`

Comment: @CBroe i have tried, it does not unfortunatly